# Xamarin.Android 6 : i went to my log file and i found thid message,i can't open any android project

Tags: xamarin

I went to my log file and I found thid message,I can't open any android project. please help

> [2016-05-08 11:48:40.7] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for
>   Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
>       Path contains adb.exe in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk). [2016-05-08 11:48:40.7] INFO: sdk:   Key
>   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
>       Path contains ndk-stack.exe in . (C:\Users\Baloi\Downloads\Programs\android-ndk-r11c-windows-x86\android-ndk-r11c).
>   [2016-05-08 11:48:40.7] INFO: sdk:   Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for
>   Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
>       Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71).

Comment: Those are all `INFO` status messages and a good sign that the various Android tools are being found. Do you have any **error** messages in the log?

Comment: no, i dont have any error message. but i found this message [2016-05-08 11:48:40.9] INFO: Did not find Xamarin.Android

Comment: in other words, it says that can not find xamarin.android and i don't knw what to do

Comment: I would try reinstalling if it is telling you that `Xamarin.Android` can not be found.